# what are the compilation steps for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, compiling

I have changed the code of Mozilla Firefox in `/usr/lib64/firefox/omni.ja`. Now, I want to compile Firefox so that the changes will get effect.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you make changes to Mozilla Firefox

1. `unzip /path/to/omni.ja -d omni`
2. Modify the files
3. `cd /path/to/omni`
4. `zip -qr9XD omni.ja *`

This method should work fine. Since you have already done all the modification now all you need is to follow step 3 and 4.

More about omni.ja(formerly omni.jar) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29).

Comment: @DKBose The same i followed but firefox is not opening. and its giving error as  XML Parsing Error: undefined entity Location: chrome://mozapps/profile/profileselection.xul Line Number 53, Column 1: